# How to get by javafx webview content iframe loaded page?

Tags: webview, javafx

In an open page loaded frame:

```
 <iframe id="wikipedia" src="http://en.wikipedia.org"></iframe>
```

Trying to get to the content:

```
Document document = webEngine.getDocument();
Element elementById = document.getElementById("wikipedia");
System.out.println(elementById.getTextContent());
```

But do not achieve results ...

Answer (score 4):

The following code works fine with javafx2:

```
Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();
HTMLIFrameElement iframeElement = (HTMLIFrameElement) doc.getElementById("wikipedia");
Document iframeContentDoc = iframeElement.getContentDocument();
Element rootElement = iframeContentDoc.getDocumentElement();
System.out.println(rootElement.getTextContent());
```